# Apply line breaks when export to Excel using SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, export

I have the below select query. I have used this data to export to Excel using C# code. The export is working and I applied `CHAR(13)` for line breaks. But after the export, the data is showing up without line breaks. But when I click the cell it is applying the line break. How do apply line breaks in export?

My query:

```
REPLACE(somestring, '<br/>', CHAR(13))
```

Comment: Try CHAR(10) instead? Char 13 is carriage return. There probably is a carriage return in your current output, it's just interpreted differently by different editors. Maybe if you open it up in notepad++ it'd have the format you expect.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Char(10)

```
REPLACE(somestring,'<br/>', CHAR(10))
```

Carriage return (Char(13)) might not show up how you expect in the editor you're using.

If that doesn't work try

```
REPLACE(somestring,'<br/>', char(13)||char(10))
```

New lines can be annoying.

Also make sure you have wrap text selected in Excel.

Comment: This is working, but the line break is showing after I click the cell. Is there anyway that excel automatically shows when opening it.

Comment: @AshokYaganti What DBMS and client are you using? So your concern is just that the line breaks aren't visible in Excel until you enter the cell?

Comment: @AshokYaganti If it's just an excel presentation thing ... use Char(10) and make sure you have wrap text selected.

Comment: @AshokYaganti Good to hear. In that case it's good to accept the answer so others don't spend additional time.